# Expose Eclipse Che to external client

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube, eclipse-che

I've installed Eclise Che within Minikube (Docker driver) ob Ubuntu 20.04 Server (running within VMware Workstation).
Everything seems to be okay. But I'm not able to access Eclipse Che from my client.

Can anybody help me to configure the network so that I can open Che on my Laptop? What are the steps to expose Che to the outer world?

The external client and the Ubuntu-VM are on the same network (192.168.108.0/24).

> minikube ip 192.168.49.2

```html
user@vm1:~$ kubectl expose deployment che --type=NodePort -n che --port 8080
service/che exposed
user@vm1:~$ kubectl get svc -n che
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
che                NodePort    10.102.134.58    <none>        8080:30532/TCP      39s
che-host           ClusterIP   10.109.70.136    <none>        8080/TCP,8087/TCP   5h45m
devfile-registry   ClusterIP   10.109.158.136   <none>        8080/TCP            5h39m
keycloak           ClusterIP   10.99.50.133     <none>        8080/TCP            5h45m
plugin-registry    ClusterIP   10.109.25.144    <none>        8080/TCP            5h39m
postgres           ClusterIP   10.105.162.37    <none>        5432/TCP            5h46m
user@vm1:~$ minikube service -n che che
|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
| che       | che  |        8080 | http://192.168.49.2:30532 |
|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Opening service che/che in default browser...
  - http://192.168.49.2:30532
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are both machines in the same network? If yes, you can check: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877

Comment: The ubuntu VM and the client who want's to access the che dashboard are in the same network. I think the problem it to access the che url from the client. The name che-che....nip.io cannot be accessed

Comment: did you use chectl to install Che? See https://github.com/che-incubator/chectl